# Application_BeginRequest takes too much time to reach the page_load of the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a strange issue in my asp.net website built in framework 4.0.
There is a button in my .aspx page which has to be clicked for a particular operation, but the application works a bit slow.
The request first goes to the "**Application_BeginRequest**" event of the global.asax and then reach the **pageLoad** event of the .aspx page.
This cycle works fine but slows down randomly some where in between.

We have put the logs in the events of the page and found that it takes more then 5 to 8 seconds to reach from the **Application_BeginRequest** to the **pageLoad** event of the .aspx page.
It means the **Application_BeginRequest** is taking too much time. We have commented the code in the  **Application_BeginRequest** and have simply written the return statement there. But the result remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is something to dig with session variable, as it goes in queue and it might lock up any page (and it reflected in _BeginRequest's totaltime)

If you play with Session, I suggest you put some code to demonstrate your scenario.

For further research please go [checkout the explanation & customSession module](http://www.ctothoughts.com/2011/11/sporadic-delays-in-beginrequest-of.html) if that suit your need.